# DAX sum of previous 3 periods value where periods are strings

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I am new to DAX and I am trying to understand how I can create a function for the following task.

I have a table with data in the following format:

| Year | Period | Account | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | P01 | 1234 | 2000 |
| 2022 | P02 | 1234 | 4000 |
| 2023 | P01 | 1234 | 1000 |

I need to find the Amount for last 3 Periods. That is, if I select year 2023 and period P01 from pivot filter, I get the amount sum of P11,P12 of year 2022 and P01 of year 2023. Similarly if I select year 2023 and period P03 from pivot filter, I get the amount sum of P01,P02,P03 of year 2023

From whatever little I understand, I am thinking along the following lines:

```
var end_period = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Period])
var end_year = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Year])
var 3mAmount = CALCULATE([Amount], Table[Period]>=start_period && Table[Period]<=end_period)
```

For P01 and P02 the start date needs to be from the last year, so

```
Var start_period = SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    DateTable[Period] = "P01", "P11",
    DateTable[Period] = "P02", "P12",
    
)
```

I don't understand how to change the year at the same time and take the relevant periods from each year only. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :**

I came up with the following approach. Although it's not showing any error but the values returned are not correct.

I created the following calculated  column (Hyperion is the data table name and the assumption is that I have only two years of data. Current year and last year)

```
= var maxyear = MAX(Hyperion[Year])  
var selectedperiod = Hyperion[Period]

var start_periodYear = SWITCH(selectedperiod,
"P01", "P11"&"-"&(maxyear-1) ,
"P02", "P10"&"-"&(maxyear-1) ,
"P03", "P01"&"-"&(maxyear),
"P04", "P02"&"-"&(maxyear),
"P05", "P03"&"-"&(maxyear),
"P06", "P04"&"-"&(maxyear),
"P07", "P05"&"-"&(maxyear),
"P08", "P06"&"-"&(maxyear),
"P09", "P07"&"-"&(maxyear),
"P10", "P08"&"-"&(maxyear),
"P11", "P09"&"-"&(maxyear),
"P12", "P10"&"-"&(maxyear)
)

var start_pd =LEFT(start_periodYear , LEN(start_periodYear )-SEARCH("-",start_periodYear)-1)
var start_yr =RIGHT(start_periodYear , LEN(start_periodYear )-SEARCH("-",start_periodYear))

var end_yr = maxyear
var end_pd = selectedperiod

var mCOGS = CALCULATE([COGS Act], FILTER(Hyperion,Hyperion[Period]>=start_pd && Hyperion[Period]<=end_pd && Hyperion[Year]>=VALUE(start_yr) && Hyperion[Year]<=VALUE(end_yr)))
return mCOGS
```

The values returned is the total grand sum for each row. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure DAX would allow for this, but maybe just some Excel functions could help you out?

[image]

Formula in `G3`:

```
=LET(x,SORT(Table1,{1,2},1),SUM(TAKE(CHOOSEROWS(x,SEQUENCE(MATCH(1,(TAKE(x,,1)=G1)*(INDEX(x,,2)=G2),0))),-3,-1)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I will have to explore these excel functions. But since my data is too large to fit in excel I was doing it through PowerQuery and DAX. I tried your approach in excel and I notice it's showing 5500 when 2023 and P01 are entered. But the expectation is if I enter P01 2023 I need sum of P01 of 2023, P12 of 2022 and P11 of 2022 (which are not there in table). So essentially it should just be P01 of 2023 which is 1000.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, yeah I anticipated all periods would be accounted for @AdnanTamimi. That makes my answer is not going to cut it.